# Continuous Deploy node js cloud service project using Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: node.js, azure, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

I currently have an Azure Cloud Service within Visual Studio containing simple Node.js web role.

This builds and packages correctly within Visual Studio locally, and deploys perfectly into the Azure cloud service.

When trying to build the solution with Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online), MSBuild fails claiming:

2016-07-01T10:09:56.7893397Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(1329,5): Error : WAT070 : The referenced assembly C:\a\1\s\CloudTool\Client\Client.exe was not found. Please make sure to build the role project that produces this assembly before building this Microsoft Azure Cloud Service Project.

...which seems to indicate it's expecting the build of the Node.js project to emit an .exe file.

I followed the same steps as mentioned in this article (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/nodejs/node-to-azure-cloud-service#help-and-support) to continuous deploy node js cloud service project.

When I googled it I found this git hub issue link (https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/428 ) in which no solution mentioned so I want to know this issue resolved or not if yes how can I solve it because I am not able to find any solution.

Comment: do you really need a webrole? can you complete the requirement in azure web apps ?

Comment: yes because web app can not fulfill my requirements.

Comment: I can get the same behavior as you and have help you submit a feedback on MS Connect page. You can track the status here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2890747