# Error : WAT070 : The referenced assembly was not found. Please make sure to build the role project that produces this assembly before building

Tags: python, msbuild, azure-cloud-services, msbuild-task, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create build definition for azure cloud services (Microsoft Azure Cloud Service Project) to automate my build process, but I'm getting the below error on the build step in TFS Online.

> *Error WAT070 The referenced assembly was not found D:\a\1\s\Python\WebRole1\WebRole1.exe". Please make sure to build the role project that produces this assembly before building this Microsoft Azure Cloud Service Project.*

I am trying to host python API using azure Flask.
I did manually deployment from VS2015 (in local machine). It's working fine.

But, I had checked the build order it was also fine. It has the web role first and cloud service at next. Still I'm getting the same error.

**Note:** I have two cloud service projects in single solution.

Comment: I assume that there be some build errors occurred when building `WebRole1` project. Are you missing some lib references which need for your project?

Comment: No, i didn't get any error on building the project.

Comment: Similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143662/continuous-deploy-node-js-cloud-service-project-using-visual-studio-team-service

Comment: Its seem like different issue. I am trying this in Visual studio online with the hosted agent. Now working to stepup on-premise build agent to analysis it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had build errors that for some reason did not appear in the errors list window.  I checked the output window and there were two errors towards the end of the build.  As soon as these were addressed, the build could complete.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this error when I build new project which have some function have not implement yet. Such as: `throw new NotImplementedException();`. I just implement this function and the error is throw away.